# Tomcat ошибка 404 при фактическом присутствии файла

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

Есть java веб приложение. Разрабатывается в Idea 14, Tomcat 8.
Неожиданно сервер перестал выдавать статические страницы, расположенные в папке WebContent.

Прикрепляю файлик конфиргурации сервера, Структура проекта, а также web.xml и другие конфигурации.
[image: Прикрепляю файлики конфиргурации сервера:]

[image: Структура проeкта]

[image: web.xml и другие конфигурации]

При открытие проекта с другой машины - всё  прекрасно работает. 
Пробовал удалять папочку .IntelliJIdea14 на всякие случай - не помогло.

Comment: Вся информация, относящаяся к вопросу должна быть в самом вопросе. Внешние ссылки могут перестать существовать, тогда ваш вопрос потеряет смысл.

Comment: @pandal **Неожиданно сервер перестал выдавать статические страницы, расположенные в папке WebContent.** Я правильно понял, что какое-то время назад, все работало?

Comment: @Владимир именно. Кажется, всё случилось после того, как дебажил приложение (но на 100% не уверен).

Comment: @pandal Это повод задуматься о распределенной системе контроля версий. Не будут возникать такие вопросы. В Intellij Idea попробуйте воспользоваться local history. Возможно поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно порт 8080 занял кто-то другой. Попробуйте другой порт. Определить кем занят порт можно при помощи консольной команды `netstat` или поискать аналогичную утилиту.

Comment: Увы, проблема осталась даже при другом порте.